# HttpRequest generating weird strings &#39; and &quot;

Tags: vb.net

This is my code these strings dont show up when I use Webrowser control btw. I think it has to be with the encoding so I explicitly assigned UTF8 to the streamreader with no success any idea about how to fix this pls?

```
    Sub HttpRequest(url As String)
    Try
        Dim myRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

        '// Get the response

        Dim webResponse As WebResponse = myRequest.GetResponse
        Dim respStream As Stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream

        '//

        Dim ioStream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8)
        Dim pageContent As String = ioStream.ReadToEnd

        MsgBox(pageContent)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is a exaple of the problem "Watch cubo Vine don't run now "

Comment: Those strings look like rather normal entities to me (see this if you need info on entities: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). Can you give a concrete example as to what character are you expecting to see and what you end up seeing?

Comment: In addition to @kaqqao excellent observation, .NET has facilities to transform entities.  Check out `System.Net.WebUtility`.

Comment: THX @Dan-o gonna check that, Just tested and it worked thx, now tell me how do i give you reputation?

Comment: @kaqqao thx you too bro u both solved my problem

Comment: i wish i could convert ur comments in the answer so i can giveu credit for solving my problem im new in this comunity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those strings look like rather normal entities to me. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) if you need info on entities.

**[By [@Dan-o](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74015/dan-o)]**

.NET has facilities to transform entities. Check out **[System.Net.WebUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**